# Unable to use LIKE function in android

Tags: android, sql, search

I am having troubles getting this sql statement to work. Can someone be kind and help me?

```
public Cursor getContactMatches(String query, String[] columns) 
{
    String selection = COL_NAME + " LIKE " + "'%" + "%'"; <---- right here
    Log.d("selection", selection);
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}
```

Comment: `select * from your_table where some_column like ( '%foobar%' )` I think you are missing the `(`, `)` and `foobar`.  Doing `select * from your_table where some_column LIKE '%%'` just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: so foobar isn't some random thing? you actually put that in the statement?

Comment: No, you're not specifying what the value you're comparing is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing in the value to compare

```
String selection = COL_NAME + " LIKE " + "'%" + yourvalue + "%'"; <---- right here
```

Comment: so would I use the query parameter?

Comment: No, you would pass the value you're trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the selection arguments then your selection string shouldn't have any quotes or % characters. The query string will be properly sql escaped automatically unless you run a raw sql query on your db. Something like the snippet bellow should get the job done.

```
String selection = COL_NAME + " LIKE ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};
```